# nodejs Add result to variable

Tags: node.js, var

Apologies, I'm not familiar with nodejs.

I have the following line that gives me a result in myResult in the first part of the httpsGet.

```
httpsGet(myRequest,  (myResult) => {

});
```

How would I then add it into the following code and append it to the 'Title' part of the variable metadata?

```
var metadata = { 
    title: "Title",
    subtitle: "Subtitle"
};
```

I've tried what would be the obvious:

```
var metadata = { 
    title: "Title" + myResult,
    subtitle: "Subtitle"
};
```

But that doesn't work.

Thanks.

**Update (to include the httpsGet function)**

```
var myRequest = 'ThisData';
var https = require('https');

function httpsGet(myData, callback) {
    var options = {
        host: 'www.example.com',
        port: 443,
        path: '/path_to.json',
        method: 'GET',
    };

    var req = https.request(options, res => {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        var returnData = "";

        res.on('data', chunk => {
            returnData = returnData + chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', () => {
            var pop = JSON.parse(returnData).data;
            callback(pop);  
        });
    });
    req.end();
}
```

My .json file response:

```
{
  "Name": "ThisData",
  "data": "this is the data I want to append to Title"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are appending the myResult inside the callback function scope. Ideally your code should look like :

```
var metadata = { 
    title: "Title",
    subtitle: "Subtitle"
};

httpsGet(myRequest, (myResult) => {
    metadata = { 
        title: "Title" + myResult,
        subtitle: "Subtitle"
    };
});
```

If you are new to node js try exploring callbacks and asynchronous functions in nodejs. I hope that will you :)

Comment: thank you for taking the time to respond. This did not work, I have updated my question with more code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am not sure with your code, but in order to access anything from callback, you can access it as a JSON object, so in your case

var metadata = { 
        title: **myResult.Title**,
        subtitle: "Subtitle"
        };

Should work. Whenever you are dealing with such things its best You first console.log the data (i.e. console.log(JSON.stringify(myResult)) and validate all expected parameters.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to respond. This did not work, I have updated my question with more code. I should already have the value extracted from the json file. Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry, but can you please elaborate your error now, I am lost with the question.

Comment: I want to append the text from the .json file "this is the data I want to append to Title" into a variable (metadata) as follows `var metadata = { 
    title: "Title" + myResult,
    subtitle: "Subtitle"
};` I'm not getting any error, it just doesn't work, the content of the .json file is not being added because I do not know how to do it. Thank you.